# Таймер обратного отчета.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужен таймер, идущий обратно, каждую полночь он обнуляется и опять показывает: до конца акции остается 24 часа 00 минут 00 секунд.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы мы вам его написали или что?

Comment: Нет. Но можно было хотя бы подсказать функцию setInterval(), Date();

Comment: Недавно делал [таймер до нового года][1]. Полуночный сброс мне лениво делать :)) Но уже реализован вывод и счетчик.

  [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/mUHmr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var s = 59 - d.getSeconds();//Функция даты вам в помощь
var m = 59 - d.getMinutes();
var h = 23 - d.getHours();

setInterval('decreaseTime()',1000);

function decreaseTime(){
  s--;
  if(s<0){
    m--;
    if(m<0){
      h--;
      if(h<0){
        h=24;
      }
      m=59;
    }
  s=59;
  }
  document.getElementById('timerDiv').innerHTML(h+':'+m+':'+s);
}
```

//[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)'s advice + prediction of ling's comment:)

```
function(){
var d = new Date();
setInterval('decreaseTime()',500);
function decreaseTime(){
  s = 59 - d.getSeconds();
  m = 59 - d.getMinutes();
  h = 23 - d.getHours();
  document.getElementById('timerDiv').innerHTML(h+':'+m+':'+s);
}
}();
```

Comment: У некоторых фаерфоксов заметно тормозят интервалы в долгих промежутках, т.е. 1000ms ~ 1s, но != 1s. Я бы создание даты тоже вынес в decreaseTime - потери небольшие, а точность выше. Опять же, подвисания системы туда же.

Comment: Кстати @knes - вы знаете что писать так `setTimeout('funcName()',1000)` - не есть хорошо? =)

Просто кто-то почитает, "поверит" и получается потом что-то типа:

    setTimeout('funcName('+param1+', '+param2+)')

И тому подобные ужасы =)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    date = new Date();
    console.log('До конца акции остается ' + 
                (23 - date.getHours()) + ' часа ' + 
                (59 - date.getMinutes()) + ' минут ' + 
                (59 - date.getSeconds()) + ' секунд.');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: 1 часа 2 минут 4 секунд будет очень красочно смотреться)))

Comment: часики тикать будут, ответ на вопрос корректный, над остальным пусь уже ТС думает =)